# How do I express this better?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am finding it rather difficult to precisely put into words a sentence that roughly means "The cow is prone to using its horns" or "It is the cow's habit to thrust its horns at others every now and then.

What is a more precise way to express this?

Answer (score 1):

“The cow tends to use its horns” may suffice.

Comment: To do what? Dig the ground, perhaps? Nah!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a phrase like ["You mess with the bull, you get the horns"](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/when_you_mess_with_the_bull,_you_get_the_horns)?  It's a proverb meaning that if you provoke someone, expect their wrath.